# Computer name program, visual C#

Tags: c#

I'm very new to Visual C#
I've already made a calculator, following a tutorial.

Now, I'm trying to make a simple program, when run will bring up a box that shows what the computer name is. I have an idea on how to do it, but I'm still learning the C# syntax.

I have made the box that pops up and it says, "This Computer's Name is:"
then I made a blank label, and I want to be able to change the label to the computer name using `System.Environment.MachineName`

Here is what I have:

```
private void name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name.Text = System.Environment.MachineName;
        //name being the name of the label
    }
```

Comment: I think the easiest way to get this resolved is for you to provide the code you have now. Please edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you want to create a form load event handler, you do this by double clicking on any blank space in the form, it will take you to the code window that is where you will want to write the following statement.

The form load event is executed before the form is displayed on screen, therefore your machine name will be displayed as soon as the window is visible.

Lets assume your form is called Form1

this is what your code will look like :

```
namespace Machine_Name
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // This is the form load event handler
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            yourLabel.Text = Environment.MachineName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you creating a Windows forms  application?

Comment: Yes I am creating one

Comment: OK, I will re write my answer for you.

Comment: Let me know how you get on

Comment: The code the op posted on original question is a label text changed event, not a form load event.

Comment: OH I didnt even notice, thanks Ryios, Do you understand what he is saying Noah? - You were trying to change the label text on a text changed event , which means it would only get the machine name if the label text was changed by some other means.

Comment: Yes that does make sense. Thank you both! My program is working perfectly fine!

Comment: How can I make it so the text stays in the center of the form? Depending on the length of the computer name

Comment: Ah, in visual studio select the label control and in the property window there is a text align property set it to the middle centre option.

Answer (score 2):

The labels text change event doesn't fire until something changes it's text.

Instead use the Forms Load event to do it, then use that line of code you have.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I'm very new